# Why is my iPhone application not using the proper localization?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization

I have an iPhone application that initially had only English and German localizations.  I just added a French localization, but when I change the user language to French it still shows the German strings.

What could be causing this odd behavior?

Comment: You think anyone will be able to give you answer on the basis of that information?

Comment: What app, what programming language, what platform, which localization system? Localizations are done so many different ways that your question is currently not answerable (as it currently reads "It's broken, help me!").

Comment: What technology are you referring to?

Comment: From other question by same user, it appears to be regarding objective-c on iOS.

Comment: My Localizable.strings is for English, French & German.It works fine for English & German, but when I switch to French it shows all data in app in german

Comment: There is probably an error somewhere.

Comment: @sherry - edit your question and add details to the question directly. Comments can end up not being viewed by people.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on the simulator or the device?
Often the localized folders  (`.lproj`) directories aren't copied into the bundles during a clean build as they should - even with a 'Clean & Clean all targets'.

Ensure this happens correctly by deleting the app from the simulator (easiest way is to 'press and hold' on the app icon in the simulator, then delete). Also, ensure the simulator doesn't keep hold of the old app data by manually deleting the app.bundle dir from the iPhone simulator directory using Finder.

Build, clean, run. Should work properly then.

If not, make sure the `fr.lproj` exists in the bundle after the build.